# How to have contents of a text file made into an array show up in a drop down list?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying create a drop down list using javascript, I loaded the contents of a text file that's long list of words using Node.js file system. I used the split() function to turn it in into an array. and then tried looping through it to show up in the drop down list on the form I'm making for a practice website. But it's not working. Any ideas?

```
 // load in contents from .txt file and create a drop down list in JS from it

// load contents from .txt file

let fs = require("fs");
let textFile = fs.readFileSync("./countries-drop-list.txt").toString('utf-8');

// turn contents into array

let textByLine = textFile.split("\n");

// loop through contents

let select = document.getElementById('chooseCountry');

for (let i = 0; i < textByLine.length; i += 1) {
    let option = document.createElement('option'),
        text = document.createTextNode(textByLine);
    option.appendChild(text);
    select.appendChild(option);

}
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: you can't use node's modules in the browser.

Comment: <option> elements go inside a <select>, <optgroup>, or <datalist> element, have you done this?

Comment: *text = document.createTextNode(textByLine);* surely you mean `text = document.createTextNode(textByLine[i]);`

Comment: Usually, an option item has a **value** and a **text** - often set using `option.value=...` and `option.text=....`.  However, as you have created an array of strings, you need to use `textByLine[i]` to target individual lines within the loop.

Comment: You can use nodejs in your backend to create the website with a templating framework like like EJS.

Answer (score 1):

From what it can be seen, you are trying to use the `fs` module of nodeJS, which **does not exist on browser.** Instead what you are going to need to do is to use `fetch` to acquire the file contents.

```
fetch('countries-drop-list.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {

    // turn contents into array
    let textByLine = text.split("\n");

    // loop through contents

    let select = document.getElementById('chooseCountry');

    for (let i = 0; i < textByLine.length; i += 1) {
        let option = document.createElement('option'),
        text = document.createTextNode(textByLine);
        option.appendChild(text);
        select.appendChild(option);

    }
    document.body.appendChild(select);
  });
```